# Securing Spring Boot 2 Actuator Prometheus End Points

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot 2 with Spring Security microservice that I have configured with Micometer/Spring Actuator.  All is well when I permitAll() on the antMatcher("/actuator/**") end points.  I am able to retrieve the Prometheus metrics via a properly configured Prometheus yaml file.

But, my microservice is not behind a firewall and thus open to the world.  I only want Prometheus to be able to access my microservice "/actuator/prometheus" end point.

I have the following configurations:

In my Spring Boot 2 microservice `ResourceServerConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTokenStore tokenStore;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("springsecurity").tokenStore(tokenStore);
  }

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous().and().authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
  }
```

For the `application.properties` file I have:

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.roles=ENDPOINT_ADMIN

# For Prometheus (and other data loggers)
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

Then for my Prometheus YAML file I have this:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: 'myservice'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
    basic_auth:
      username: 'user'
      password: 'password'
```

When I go to /targets in Prometheus I get "server returned HTTP status 401".

I fully assume I'm not understanding something quite right.  Is there a way for me to properly do this?  Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe you expect your endpoint to be protected with basic auth? You might try editing if that is true to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same need and I have solved it in the following way, it is quite simple.

First, it is necessary to configure a **username** and **password** in the Spring Security section of the microservice within the application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: prometheus
      password: prometheus
```

Afterwards, you configure that username and password in the prometheus.yml just as you have it

```
- job_name: 'iot-processor'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['iot-processor:8080']
    basic_auth:
      username: "prometheus"
      password: "prometheus"
```

You can limit the exposed points or enable them all, I have the following configuration for my needs:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

That's all, if I access without username and password I would see the following page

[image]

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Was the prometheus system and the services system in the internal network.
If they was in the same internal network, you can use internal IP to get actuator data.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the credentials which are the same as

```
spring.security.user.name
spring.security.user.password
```

to Prometheus, in order to pass

```
-job_name:
 ...
 basic_auth:
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
```

you can used ***htpasswd*** to crypt password after to set in prometheus